# Tortoise SVN repository, how to get localhost address of repository (http) instead of (file://)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When i am creating repository, I always get a repository address as `file://thisfolder/thisfolder/repository`

I wanna use my localhost address for any repository I create by TortoiseSVN. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup an SVN server to access your repository through the HTTP protocol.

See this FAQ at the TortoiseSVN site for confirmation: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#noserver

You should get a server like VisualSVN: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/

Comment: hmm.. actually i don't wanna use VisualSVN. I have used it before, and it adds up an another interface inbetween to bother about. 

I wanted, somehow tortoise svn can directly start providing the localhost path.

Comment: @VishwasGagrani TortoiseSVN alone can't do this. You need a server anyway.